# Running screen and immediately run other commands

Tags: gnu-screen

I could not figure out how to start a screen session, and in that attached screen session to run a command without human intervention. Expected behavior is:

```
[me@me ~]# screen -S name -L --mystery_flag 'hostname;echo yes;echo no'
#new screen session
[me@me ~]# hostname
me
[me@me ~]# echo yes
yes
[me@me ~]# echo no
no
[me@me ~]#
```

I looked by only found ways to send commands to a detatched session of screen, or to have the screen session close after it sends a command like `screen -S name "command"`. I would like for the session to stay open, since it will be used to run an interactive script.

Comment: Since you give `screen` a command to run instead of a shell, it will run that command and then terminate, just like it would otherwise run your shell and then terminate when the shell exits. You could try launching a shell as the last command, but I'm currently uncertain whether it understands a list of `;`-delimited commands at all (can't test at the moment).

Comment: So then how would you make a script that runs screen, and then a bunch of commands and doesn't terminate afterwards? Is it even possible? Or maybe needs a different program similar to screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU `screen` takes a number of options, and then an optional command to start within the screen session.  If no command is given, the `screen` session will contain an interactive shell session.  The `screen` session terminates when the command that it runs terminates, no matter whether it's a command given on the command line of `screen`, or the shell that it otherwise runs.

You have two issues:

1. You want to run more than a single command.
2. You want the session to not terminate at the end, but instead leave you in an interactive shell session, within `screen`.

To solve the first of these, make the command that `screen` starts be

```
sh -c 'hostname; echo yes; echo no'
```

This is a single command that starts an in-line `sh -c` script.  This script runs your commands.  You may want to use `bash -c` in place of `sh -c` if the script you're running requires `bash` (your example does not).

To solve the second issue, consider starting an interactive shell as the last step in the list of commands that the `sh -c` script runs:

```
sh -c 'hostname; echo yes; echo no; exec bash -i'
```

The `exec bash -i` starts an interactive `bash` shell session (the `exec` makes it *replace* the `sh -c` shell).

Running this within a `screen` session:

```
screen sh -c 'hostname; echo yes; echo no; exec bash -i'
```

GNU `screen` will terminate once the `bash -i` shell session terminates.

Comment: Thanks, this works!